# Angularjs, link click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This might sound like a stupid question but I can't seem to figure out the answer, I'm studying angularjs these days and I've successfully generated the page and they have links that looks like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="evsi in evz" class="ng-scope">
<a href="#" likey="{{evsi.key}}" id="sideli" class="ng-binding">Link text</a>
</div>
```

What I want to do is when the link is clicked I need to retrive the likey value attached to it and pass it where an event is triggered.

So I used the following code

```
$('#sideli').on('click', function(){
    var linkkey = $(this).data('likey');
});
```

However this doesn't get the likey value i needed, Even when i set up a simple alert event to check whether the link is clicked the alert doesn't show up. Where is the error and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: check browser console for any JavaScript errors..

Comment: THis is not angular way to do. Use ng-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you html:

```
<a ng-click="doWhatYouWant(evsi)" likey="{{evsi.key}}" 
           id="sideli" class="ng-binding" href="javascript:void(0)">Link text</a>
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.doWhatYouWant = function(evsi){
   console.log(evsi.key);
}
```

Keep in mind you are using angular. There is no need to query for elements and bind a click event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ngClick for that.

```
<div ng-repeat="evsi in evz" class="ng-scope">
  <a href="#" ng-click="linkkey = evsi.key">Link text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrive value of attribute, use `attr` method:

```
$('#sideli').on('click', function(){
     var linkkey = $(this).attr('likey');
});
```

But better way is to use angular, as @Michael suggested.